# Cannot Add Multiple users to a SPFieldUserValueCollection without removing the previous one

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

please help I Cannot Add Multiple users to a SPFieldUserValueCollection without removing the previous one. evertime I add to my collection the previous user gets removed. here is my code below.

```
spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

SPFieldUserValueCollection usercollection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(spWeb, LearningCalendar_Item["Course Attendies"].ToString());
usercollection.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(spWeb, SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID, SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name.ToString()));
LearningCalendar_Item["Course Attendies"] = usercollection;
LearningCalendar_Item.Update();

spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

SPUser user = spWeb.EnsureUser(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName);   

SPFieldUserValueCollection values = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)LearningCalendar_Item["Course Attendies"];

values.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(web, user.ID, user.Name));

LearningCalendar_Item["Course Attendies"] = values;

LearningCalendar_Item.Update()

spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```